# Holding value after printing from MQTT

Tags: c++, arduino, raspberry-pi, adc

I have a question for all of you out there: is it possible to hold a value in memory after printing it? I will give you an example:

Nodered created interface there is a slider with numbers like slider from 20 to 30. You slide it and choose a value like 25, then that value is send back to the Arduino or ESP serial monitor, there is a command that you can create a variable for that number 25.

OK that all good but I understand that when you send the number it triggers the variable 1 time, and I need a function that can remember the value when it's time to use it.

I am building a greenhouse (how original) and I want to use it wireless, like set the watering of the plants when the temperature is at 22°C, light percentage at 10%, and time from 19:00 to 22:00 to water it.

And the question is: how can I use the variable that was set by the slider in nodered to water my plants at that exact temperature which was set.

This is the code I will be using at the end of `mqttFloodInterval`. I can set what variable I'm gonna get from nodered.

```cpp
void mqttCallback(char* topic, byte* message, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("MQTT message received on topic: ");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print(". Message: ");
  String messageTemp;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)message[i]);
    messageTemp += (char)message[i];
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(messageTemp);
  if (String(topic) == mqttFloodInterval) {
    Serial.print("*** (Flood Interval Received)");
  }
}
```

Edit for ocrdu something like this:

```
if (String(topic) == mqttFloodInterval) {
    Serial.print("*** (Flood Interval Received)");
   mqttFloodInterval = wtrtemp;
  }
   if(wtrtemp == 23){
 digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, HIGH); // turn on pump 5 seconds
     delay(5000);
  } 
     else {
     
       digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW);  // turn off pump 5 seconds
      delay(5000);
  }
```

And do all the `if`s like `if (wtrtemp == 24)`, `if (wtrtemp == 25)`.... and so on.

Comment: The question is incredibly hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish. I guess in your head it's clear as day when reading the question since you are the constructor of this project and have a goal in your mind. But i highly suggest to try to tell what your are trying to do and what the current problem that you have hit like your explaining it to someone that has never seen a system like this before :)

Comment: ```Serial.print("*** (Flood Interval Received)");``` After this command I can turn on the led or something else, but I need to hold the value in programs memory if I set it to let's say 25 the number should be hold in memory for later use like when the sensors percent value drop below 25 then some command will take effect to turn on a relay for 5 sec to water the plant. And the problem is that when you send the value below the command I wrote in the start it triggers the  program one time and that it. I need a function that can hold the value for later use.

Comment: Because when you use the slider it sends the value just one time. And the slider is used to chose what temp the it should reach to water the plant

Comment: This is the biggest problem I face in this project which will make or break the program :D

Answer (score 0):

The `String messageTemp` is only available inside of the `mqttCallback()` function, which, if I understand you correctly, is not what you want.

If you make `messageTemp` global, by moving the line `String messageTemp;` to the top of the code, just before `setup()`, you can then use it everywhere in your code.

Note that you will now have to empty it before you get new data from `mqttCallback()`, or the new data will be added to the data you already have in `messageTemp`.

You can do this by adding the line `messageTemp.remove(0);` in the spot where you removed `String messageTemp;` in the `mqttCallback()` function.

The same applies to other `String`s that are created in the `mqttCallback()` function.

Comment: I am not 100% sure that this is the answer but I will try it tomorrow. I was thinking that after function (if) I can set a variable like ```wtrtemp``` and do another if function to ask if the ```wtrtemp``` is 22C  and light >10.  ```wtrtemp = 22``` but like I said I think if get an answer from mqqt its just once and maybie with your code I can do that

Comment: I edited the code above of how i was thinking of doing it

Answer (score 0):

Yet again i did not fully understand what exactly your goal was here so i gave you two options in the code below. if you choose the code snippets from `//*option 1` you will simply be able to store one temperature at a time to the global memory of your esp32, this is the simplest, so if this works pick this option.

`//*option 2` is instead a list of temperature values for storing in the global memory, so if you wish to use alot of temperature for future reference, this will be your choice.

```
//----Two options choose one of them you prefer----//
//----whichever option you choose use the same option for all the code below----//

//*option 1
//store a single temperature value to a global variable
int global_memory_single_temperature = -1; //-1 not defined yet

//*option 2
//if you want to store multiple values, lets say 500 values use this:
int global_memory_multiple_temperature[500];
int current_temperatureValue = 0;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
}
void loop()
{

  //this happens some time in the future after you have recieved a value
  if (String(topic) == mqttFloodInterval)
  {
    Serial.print("*** (Flood Interval Received)");

    //----Two options choose one of them you prefer----//

    //*option 1
    //store a single wtrtemp to a global variable
    global_memory_single_temperature = wtrtemp;

    //*option 2
    //if you would like to store alot of temperatures for later use:
    global_memory_multiple_temperature[current_temperatureValue++];

    mqttFloodInterval = wtrtemp;
  }

  //Below can happen once your timer? i think hits the goal timer..

  //*if you choose option 1:
  //Later to check what the wtrtemp was use this:
  if (global_memory_single_temperature == 23)
  {
    digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, HIGH); // turn on pump 5 seconds
    delay(5000);
  }
  else
  {

    digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW); // turn off pump 5 seconds
    delay(5000);
  }

  //*if you choose option 2:
  //or if you want to use multiple temperatures that are stored use this:
  for (int i = 0; i < current_temperatureValue; i++)
  {
    //this will loop through all previous stored temperatures and do the stuff below
    int currentWtrTempValue = global_memory_multiple_temperature[i];
    if (currentWtrTempValue == 23)
    {
      digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, HIGH); // turn on pump 5 seconds
      delay(5000);
    }
    else
    {

      digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW); // turn off pump 5 seconds
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}
```

-Btw, i hope you already have this section in your setup() part of the sketch.

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(RELAY_PIN, OUTPUT);    // sets the relay pin available for digitalWrites...
}
```