# Esp-32 invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, c, arduino, mqtt, esp32

Hello I have a problem with some variable conversions and a problem is that when try to compile the code a get this error message. Why couldn't it convert?

I put the `wtrtemp` as a String tried changing it to int and float and const char same problem. the Mqtt just prints out a number from a slider. which is sent from node red

invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

```
//MQTT incoming
#define mqttFloodInterval "greenHouse/floodInt"
#define mqttFloodDuration "greenHouse/floodDur"
#define mqttLightsOnDuration "greenHouse/lightsOnDur"
#define mqttLightsOffDuration "greenHouse/lightsOffDur"
//MQTT Setup End
```

```
int wtrtemp;
```

```
void topicsSubscribe(){
   client.subscribe(mqttFloodInterval);
   client.subscribe(mqttFloodDuration);
   client.subscribe(mqttLightsOnDuration);
   client.subscribe(mqttLightsOffDuration);
}
```

```
  Serial.print("MQTT message received on topic: ");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print(". Message: ");
  messageTemp.remove(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)message[i]);
    messageTemp += (char)message[i];
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(messageTemp);
  if (String(topic) == mqttFloodDuration) {
    wtrtemp = mqttFloodDuration; // The problem is here 
    Serial.print("*** (Flood Interval Received)");
  }
  if(wtrtemp == 23){
 digitalWrite(15, HIGH); // turn on pump 5 seconds
     delay(5000);
  } 
     else {
     
       digitalWrite(15, LOW);  // turn off pump 5 seconds
      delay(5000);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `mqttFloodDuration`?

Comment: from the error seen, `mqttFloodDuration` is most likely a variable of type `const char*` which means it is probably a string, if the string is supposed to be numerals, then you will need additional code to convert it into integer

Comment: Edited the code for what is mqttFloodDuration

Comment: WARhead probably right gonna search for how to convert ```const char*``` to ```string or int``` :)

Comment: What would you expect "greenHouse/floodDur" to be as an int? What is the magic number 23?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the environment to test your case, but i highly suggest if your'e trying to convert a string to int that you use atol() since the esp32 framework supports it.

`int x = (int)atol("550");`

So in your case: `wtrtemp = (int)atol(mqttFloodDuration); // The problem is here`

If that doesn't solve your case(can't 100% remember if atol used parameter took a const char* or char*) so incase it insists on char* try use this instead:
`wtrtemp = (int)atol((char*)mqttFloodDuration); // The problem is here`

If you wish to go on the dangerous but easy road of using String class, then you can very easily set a String by

```
String xx = "hello world";
int xx_int = xx.toInt();
```

But underhood that function also does the atol() function referred to above so keep that in mind if you are trying to be efficient in your memory allocation and usage of the esp32 onboard ram.

Comment: Yea thx it worked I can compile the code. now I need to fix my logical code :D <3 cause I get the value but the led doesn't light up :(

Comment: That will clear the warning, yes, but given the definition of `mqttFloodDuration`, it seems unlikely to produce the desired behavior.

Comment: @LukasKaščiukevičius Post a new question for your next question about the led, so that people can benefit from how to solve that in the future. I will be happy to guide you as much as i'm capable.

Comment: i have a thread created which is still unclear for my understanding. Which I'm still trying to figure it out 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65145054/holding-value-after-printing-from-mqtt/65148031#65148031

Answer (score 2):

Your `mqttFloodDuration` is a macro that expands to the string literal `"greenHouse/floodDur"`.  The error message is telling you, correctly, that this is not correctly type matched with a variable of type `int`, such as your `wtrtemp`.

Moreover, you do seem to expect `wrtemp` to take a genuine integer value because you later compare it to the integer constant `23`, but it is unclear from the code presented how the string `"greenHouse/floodDur"` corresponds to an integer.  Possibly there is some kind of lookup function you could use to get a corresponding value, but as far as I can tell, that would be specific to your project.

Comment: Yea I wrote some explanation about what I'm doing but didn't really specify what I'm doing. Theres a slider in node red that can send back a number from 20-30 etc. that number will be used as a waterpump for watering if the wtrtemp is 25 and outtemp is >20 then water for 5 sec

Comment: @LukasKaščiukevičius, the lack of clarity I spoke of is not about the *purpose* of your program but rather about its *functionality*.  If it at all makes sense to try to obtain an integer from `mqttFloodDuration` (defined as it is) then the appropriate mechanism for doing so is specific to your project. In particular, `(int)atol(mqttFloodDuration)` will always evaluate to 0, so it seems unlikely to be what you are really looking for.

Comment: Yea like you said the variable comes back zero after using command ```(int)atol``` is there other way to convert the char value?

Comment: @LukasKaščiukevičius, as I said before, any such mechanism that may exist is *specific to your project*.  The nature of any association between that string and a numeric value is unclear from what you have presented, and not standard in any way that I recognize.  Possibly the string is the key of a hashtable or database entry.  Possibly it's simply the wrong thing to use, and in that case maybe there is a different macro that expands to the wanted value instead of a (somehow-)related string.